# React keys when handling dynamic children. What are they for? How are they used behind the scenes?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/components/records.js.coffee

  @Records = React.createClass
    ...
    render: ->
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'records'
        React.DOM.h2
          className: 'title'
          'Records'
        React.DOM.table
          className: 'table table-bordered'
          React.DOM.thead null,
            React.DOM.tr null,
              React.DOM.th null, 'Date'
              React.DOM.th null, 'Title'
              React.DOM.th null, 'Amount'
          React.DOM.tbody null,
            for record in @state.records
              React.createElement Record, key: record.id, record: record
```

What is the key prop for? How is it handled behind the scenes during React's reactive data process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` helps React keep track of a component rendered from an array across multiple renders as it potentially changes position in or is added to/removed from the array. For example, if you first render components for

```
[record3, record2, record1]
```

and later render

```
[record4, record3, record2, record1]
```

React will naively destroy all the components and instantiate and render new ones in their place, because React thinks `record3` became `record4`, `record2` become `record3`, and so on, and `record1` was added to the end. This results in four new components, even if the children have a `shouldComponentUpdate` that would have returned false:

```
record3   -change->   record4
record2   -change->   record3
record1   -change->   record2
          --add--->   record1
```

However, if you uniquely identified the components rendered from each record via a `key` attribute, React would recognize that `record4` was added to the beginning, allowing the parent to rerender more efficiently:

```
          --add--->   record4
record3    -same-     record3
record2    -same-     record2
record1    -same-     record1
```

This is especially important if the child components were stateful in some way.

`key` properties are also used in React's animation system, to determine if one component is different from another component (and thus should be transitioned in or out).